# How recover boot drive? Mount the macOS drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, startup, mount

I have problem. MacBook Pro 15 2010 A1286 with two OSes on-board: Win7 on BootCamp and macOS.

The second drive (which is installed instead of the DVD) is turned off when macOS worked. The plume fell off.

macOS told me that drive was turned off incorrectly. After a reboot macOS didn't start.

The boot record was unmounted...

I used <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (recovery mode) to boot. I tried to use Disk Utility, and `diskutil`, to mount the drive, but without success.

[image: Disk Utility screenshot]

[image: diskutil screenshot]

Comment: `The plume fell off`... do you mean `the plug fell out`? What is the "plume"?

Comment: @Greenonline I mean sata cable fell out yes. HDD hot disconected. Now i cant mount MAC os boot record.

Comment: Post the output from the following commands. `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`, `fdisk /dev/disk0` and `export LC_CTYPE="ASCII";  diskutil umountDisk disk0; dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=3 | vis -cfw`